# Creating HTML structure and using functions in append

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use function in jQuery `.append` somehow? I need something like this:

```
$("<tbody>").append(function(){
    for (i = 0; i < Test1.length; i++){
        Test1[i]
    }
})
```

Why is everything okay in this case

```
$("<tr>").append(
    $("<th>").append("#"),
    $("<th>").append(THeaders[1]),
    $("<th>").append("Tuesday"),
    $("<th>").append("Wednesday"),
    $("<th>").append("Thurdsday"),
    $("<th>").append("Friday"),
    $("<th>").append("Saturday")
)
```

But I receive elements without "< th>" in next option:

```
$("<tr>").append(
    $.each(THeaders, function(i, d){
        $("<th>").append($('<th></th>').text(d));
    })
)
```

where

```
var THeaders = ["#", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thurdsday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
```

Comment: Can you explain more on what you expected and what you actually get instead? Also could you post your code as a [mcve], because the partial code as it stands is not enough to see y`our problem. It's easiest to use a function on an iteration using `.each()`, $.map()`, etc. or as a callback `.on('event', function() {`, but yes you can [append-function](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-function)

Comment: you try to append a function into a `<tbody>` element.

Comment: @zer00ne Okay, I'll just post all the code. I'm coding schedule for university and I need to create table from the JSON file. I'm expecting to receive next html part: https://pastebin.com/bczdjVEW. So I made a little script to receive data from JSON and convert to HTML: https://pastebin.com/UK42sdBp. All the data received correctly, but I have troubles to insert it in the html code and correctly recreate html in the js file.

Comment: @rm4, oh, I realised that now, but is there a way to execute this function in right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use JS's `.map()` to retrieve every value and a Template Literal ``` `` ``` to wrap your values in `TR` tags

**ES6**

```js
var THeaders = ["#", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thurdsday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

$('thead tr').append( THeaders.map(val => `<th>${val}</th>`) );
```

```css
th{border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr></tr></thead>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Or the JS old fashioned way:

```js
var THeaders = ["#", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thurdsday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

$('thead tr').append( THeaders.map(function(val) { return '<th>'+ val +'</th>'; }) );
```

```css
th{border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead><tr></tr></thead>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

**The *jQuery* way** you were trying to use - would miss some sort of `.map`,  `return` and $Element construction like

```js
var THeaders = ["#", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thurdsday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

$("<tr/>", {
  append: THeaders.map(function(val){
     return $('<th/>', {text: val});
  }),
  appendTo: 'thead'
})
```

```css
th{border: 1px solid #ddd;}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead></thead>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: @cale_b  I would think by now ES6 is the default context on Javascript, and if ES3/ES5 are required, it should be stipulated.  We've got to move on at some point..

Comment: Personally I would use the `.text()` just to avoid any issues that could be caused by escape tags etc.. eg.. `THeaders.map(val => $('<th>').text(val))`

Comment: Thank you, that worked properly for day names, but didn't work for strings with html code. I copy-paste my commentary from above to make this clear: Okay, I'll just post all the code. I'm coding schedule for university and I need to create table from the JSON file. I'm expecting to receive next html part: pastebin.com/bczdjVEW. So I made a little script to receive data from JSON and convert to HTML: pastebin.com/UK42sdBp. All the data received correctly, but I have troubles to insert it in the html code and correctly recreate html in the js file.

Comment: @Ilikebigbugs you're over.complicating your life with all those nested `append`s. Take a look at `Template Literals` (if you can afford to use ES6), Google it. Than simply create a HTML template and use `${some.data}` to insert dynamic values into it. Your code is gone already too bad - too far - to be savaged.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan It is okay, I've never done coding before, so I understand that this "work" is too bad :)

Comment: @Ilikebigbugs if you've never done coding before than it's an amazing job! Really. Just, stop now. Google for Template Literals. You'll save yourself a load of time. Than when you hit the wall again feel free to come back with another question. :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sadly, but I can't afford to use ES6, because the biggest part of traffic will be via mobile browser, but, as I see, mobile browsers doesn't support ES6

Comment: @Ilikebigbugs than use standard string concatenation. `"<div>"+ some.data +"</div>"` etc. After you construct your template with the served data you can include that HTML string into any element like `$("#page").append(myTemplateWithData)` - Or learn to use compilation programs in Node.js that by using Babel will transpile ES6 to ES5 - So you can freely use ES6 features and see your code converted to good'ol'JS.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Honestly, I did this variant when I started (the one with template), but I thought that it "isn't smart and beatiful", because isn't it better to use some series with arrays then create template by hand?

Comment: @Ilikebigbugs indeed :) it is. But not using `.append()` like that... with nesting etc... And BTW the fastest way is to use string concatenation and append the final result only once, instead of doing heavy DOM and memory manipulations (when not needed).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following shoudl give you an idea where to go?

```js
var THeaders = ["#", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thurdsday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var trid = $('#list');
$.each(THeaders, function(i, d){
    trid.append('<th>' + d + '</th>');
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
<tr id="list">

</tr>
</table>
```